# wp_Query with mutuplea values returns all posts

Tags: php, wp-query, meta-query

I have a dynamic form that brings the data from the URL and searches the DB with a wp_Query.
It works great if I insert a dingle value manually.
but if I pass the data from the URL I receive all the posts.
even if I manually insert an array with multiple values it returns all posts.

here is the query:
the first part works great.
the second one `cost_per_month_ipcenter_filter_new` is the one with the problem.

```
    $args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    's' => $_GET['s'],
    'post_type' => 'ipcenters',
    'meta_query'     =>  array(
         'relation '  => 'AND',
        array(
            'meta_key'      => 'setupfee_ipcenter',
            'meta_value'        => $setupfee_ipcenter_val,
            'meta_compare'   => $setupfee_ipcenter_comp,
        ),
        array(
            'key'       => 'cost_per_month_ipcenter_filter_new',
            'value'     =>  array('101-150', '0-50'),
            'compare'   => '=',

        )
    ),
);


$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

if I write

`'value'     =>  '101-150',`

it works.
I tried `'value'     =>  ['101-150', '0-50'],`
This is the same as the written above but it still doesn't work.

this is how it appears in the url
`cost_per_month_ipcenter_filter_new%5B%5D=0-50&cost_per_month_ipcenter_filter_new%5B%5D=101-150`

the final result it to place the `$_GET['cost_per_month_ipcenter_filter_new']`  as the value array.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "the first part works great" - are you sure? Because meta query clauses (arrays in the `meta_query` arg) use `key`, `value` and `compare`. I.e. Without the `meta_` part. And `'value' => '101-150'` works because the value is a string. So when it's an array of values, `compare` should be `IN`, i.e. `'compare' => 'IN'`.

Comment: Thanks! it really was the compare value, the `IN` really fixed it